# Error ZED installing with Cmake and openCV

Tags: opencv, cmake, filepath, zed-sdk

i would like to install my ZED Camera from Stereolabs. Iwas following each step precisely (https://www.stereolabs.com/documentation/overview/getting-started/application-development.html#installation) but it didn't work. From the errorlog it says, that the path of the config and directory is wrong. So I put it manually but still going to the wrong file and directory.[Errorlog and my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hyxX.png)

```
    CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/ZED SDK/dependencies/opencv_3.1.0/OpenCVConfig.cmake:166 (message):
  Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has no binaries compatible with your
  configuration.

  You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV
  library.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:41 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:41 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/ZED SDK/dependencies/opencv_3.1.0/OpenCVConfig.cmake

  but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
  NOT FOUND.
```

Thanks for any help!

Horst

Comment: `From the errorlog it says, that the path of the config and directory is wrong.` - It says that you have OpenCV incompatible with your configuration. As tutorial suggests to use `Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64` generator, I guess OpenCV binaries are precompiled for it. But you use `Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64` generator.

Comment: Ok this could be the problem, I'm using VS 2015. But I don't find VS 2014... Is it still possible to download?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/ but you need to join some azure program. The page will show the download file is missing and will show the link to join the program. I found community edition 2015